# Mathematica C WSTP example never returns

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, api

```
#include "wstp.h"

int main(){
    WSENV env;
    WSLINK link;
    int error;

    env = WSInitialize((WSEnvironmentParameter)0);
    if(env == (WSENV)0)
    { /* Unable to initialize WSTP environment */ }

    link = WSOpenString(env, "-linkcreate -linkprotocol IntraProcess", &error);
    if(link == (WSLINK)0 || error != WSEOK){ /* Unable to create link object */ }

    /* ... */

    WSPutFunction(link, "EvaluatePacket", 1);
    WSPutFunction(link, "ToExpression", 1);
    WSPutString(link, (const char *)"3+4/Sqrt[19.2]");
    WSEndPacket(link);

    /* send the packet */
    if(! WSFlush(link)){ /* unable to flush an outgoing data buffered in link */ }



    WSClose(link);
    WSDeinitialize(env);
    return 0;
}
```

This above code example compiles fine, However when I try to execute it I see the following output

> Link created on: xcj99hr_ipq
>
> ^C^C

The program doesn't return and Hitting Ctrl+C doesn't quit. I know I am not capturing any return, but shouldn't it return though ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What do you expect the program to do?  Where did you get this code from?  It seems to have several problems.  It's not really possible to comment on this until you explain what you want to do.

Comment: I am actually trying to import a mathematica .m package from C++ and call those functions, However as I am new to WSTP I was trying to try some easy codes and see what happens, I understand that I can read the output  after `WSEndPacket` call, but even If I don't read the output I expect these calls to returns and reach `returns 0` and the program ends. However I see no output and the entire program just freezes and doen't return at all.

Comment: So the answer to my question is that you want to call Mathematica code from C. That means that your C code must 1. launch a Mathematica kernel 2. connect to it through MathLink.  Use the `factor.c` example as reference to do this. Also google for "ML_tut" and read through section 2 in its entirety.

Comment: I can't comment on each bit of your code without testing it, but some obvious problems: 1. you didn't launch the Mathematica kernel 2. you are trying to use the IntraProcess protocol to communicate between different processes.  I suggest you drop this code and start again based on the resources I mention above.

Comment: Googling for ML_Tut now points to Machine Learning resources...